# When to override a validation method in Page Lifecycle

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

So I have made a custom required field validator that turns the background of a textbox red. For this I have implemented a custom control that inherits from required field validator.

Everything is working great and the control functions properly. The only thing is that the control does a post back and the error of the custom required field validator is not caught in the validation section of the page life cycle.

```
public class MVADRequiredFieldValidator : RequiredFieldValidator
    {
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        if(Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            Validate();
            var mvadRequiredFieldValidator = this;
            var controlToValidate = ControlToValidate;

            TextBox tbToChange = (TextBox)FindControl(controlToValidate);

            if(!IsValid)
            {
                if (tbToChange != null)
                {
                    tbToChange.CssClass = "error";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (tbToChange != null)
                {
                    tbToChange.CssClass = "nonError";
                }
            }
        }
        //OnInit(e);

    }
}
```

I know about the asp.net page life-cycle but I have not yet found a method to override that will register the error with the collection of errors on the page.

Thanks

Comment: I know javascript... I am not using it because I need to make this control for a controls toolkit that n00b developers will get when they enter the project. This control will be used more than 1000 times in the project and I do not want javascript everywhere. But thanks for the -1.

Comment: @Marwa: How do you do Server-side validation in Javascript?

Comment: couldn't you just use a custom validator instead. That would be easier

Comment: @Marwan: You really shouldn't downvote someone for not being well-versed in something. That's not what downvotes are for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about EvaluateIsValid(); Seems to be what you want

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basevalidator.evaluateisvalid.aspx

from this post

http://forums.asp.net/t/1049481.aspx/1

This seems really similar to waht you want to do

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/enhacedvalidator.aspx

Comment: I've added another example which seems very similar. Only other suggestion is are you sure you are calling  base.EvaluateIsValid(); Are the validation groups correct and try calling Page.Validate("validationGroup") to test. Just some ideas. It just seems very doable

Comment: That is what I want to do but I and it works like mine does. Lets say I have two textboxes. one has a regular required field val and the other a custom val. if i click the button, the reg fires. Then i fill in the tb for reg. then click button and page posts back. Then my custom validator fires. I do not want page postback.

Comment: I'm a bit confused now. What you are doing will require postbacks - i've misunderstood maybe. If you want validation without postback that you can wrap as a component for reuse you could consider a jquery plugin maybe? Or custom validators expose a client validate function but this is going away from reuse